# css mix-blend-mode: difference issue in safari

Tags: css, mix-blend-mode

I am trying the below mouseover effect using `mix-blend-mode`.
It is working as expected in Chrome and Firefox.

```css
.btn-anim {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 1.25rem;
  color: #fff;
  --x: 66%;
  --y: -34%;
}

.btn-anim:after,
.btn-anim:before {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  transition: transform cubic-bezier(0.88, 0.03, 0, 0.94) 0.3s;
}

.btn-anim:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  --tw-bg-opacity: 1;
  background-color: rgba(243, 109, 69, var(--tw-bg-opacity));
  z-index: -1;
  transform: translateX(var(--x));
}

.btn-anim:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  --tw-bg-opacity: 1;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, var(--tw-bg-opacity));
  mix-blend-mode: difference;
  transform: translateX(var(--y));
}

.btn-anim:hover:before {
  transform: translateX(0);
}

.btn-anim:hover:after {
  transform: translateX(-100%);
}
```

```html
<a href="" class="btn-anim">Learn More About Services</a>
```

Codepen - https://codepen.io/felixaj/pen/GROJyoR

Safari shows a black patch. What is the fix for the issue?

[image]

Or is there any other way I can make the same effect ?

### Edit ---

This works only if background colour is white .

Is there a better way to achieve this effect when used on top of light gray background color ?

Codepen updated with a button in a div with gray background.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Found some help from Jonathan at https://greensock.com/forums/topic/21802-issues-with-safari-perspective-mix-blend-mode/

### A solution here

Is to add `transform: translate3d(0,0,0);` to `.btn-anim`.

It puts it on the same rendering layer and Safari can then apply the effect same as FF/Chrome.

Comment: Interestingly enough, this solution also solved an issue where Safari wasn't applying mix-blend-mode to SVG elements. Thank you!